# Printing a Text File from Command Prompt

Tags: windows, text, printing, command-prompt

Alright, this is outside my area of expertise but so here's what I'm trying to do:

→ I have a POS (Point of Sale) receipt printer. I have the drivers installed for it and can print a test page with it. I can also print from notepad++ (for example), although it leaves a lot of empty space. This printer is set as the default printer.

→ I want to be able to print a single line to the printer using some automated process in Windows. My initial thought was to have the line I wanted to print in a text file and then to use:

```
print C:\filename.txt
```

from Command Prompt. However, this results in

```
C:\filename.txt is currently being printed
```

but nothing is printed. I am unfamiliar with ESC/POS and do not understand where to incorporate those commands either. Basically, printing a txt file from Command Prompt is my first necessity though. Any help?

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, it is offtopic on Stack Overflow. You might want to try on http://superuser.com/?as=1, not sure it'll be ontopic there though.

Comment: I am programming a batch file and need this command to work for the batch file to work. I believe batch files are still considered programming.

Comment: Also, someone may have a solution that involves Python of which I am more familiar, but the task seems capable of being done via a batch file.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
START /MIN NOTEPAD /P yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try

```
copy /b yourfilename yourportname
```

where yourportname may be `PRN:` or `LPT1:` or whatever.

Comment: Having said that though, it would be raw bytes delivered to the printer - noth through any drivers. That's the way I run POS or label printers. The text you'd need to deliver would need to be in accordance with that particular printer's individual **P**rinter **C**ontrol **L**anguage - and there's no standard. That's what the driver does - convert Windows-talk to the particular printer's PCL.

Comment: What's the port name for AdobePDF printer? I tried googling it but couldn't get my hands on something.